# How to push to another upstream

Tags: git, github

When I run `git branch --av` I got theses lines.

[image]

I am trying to push changes to different remote urls. What does The last line indicate? And how can I push to this upstream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just say the name of the remote you want to push to. For example, if you are on `master`:

```
git push upstream master
```

Comment: And if what you mean is push to a branch with a different name from the local one: `git push a-remole local-branch:remote-branch`